# How do I merge 2 directories with the same name in shell script

Tags: shell

I am programming something and one of the things I need to do is to merge 2 directories. How do I do that? Rsync does not work. I tried compiling but after a few seconds it gave me errors.

These are the commands I ran (I ran these because the INSTALL.md said so):

```
sudo apt install -y gcc g++ gawk autoconf automake python3-cmarkgfm
sudo apt install -y acl libacl1-dev
sudo apt install -y attr libattr1-dev
sudo apt install -y libxxhash-dev
sudo apt install -y libzstd-dev
sudo apt install -y liblz4-dev
sudo apt install -y libssl-dev
./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Comment: @mattb i added the commands i ran

Comment: Cool, that'll stop downvotes. I edited you question to use code highlighting (which you can do with the ``` before and after the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple and efficient way is with `cp`

```
cp --force --archive --update --link ./img1/. ./img2
```

copy all files of ./img1 directory to ./img2 directory and replaces older items.

the `--link` option is for merging directories without moving any data.

Comment: does that work if both of then have stuff in it?

Comment: yes, and replaces the existing files/directories if there is a file/directory with that name.